# Creating a calculator in c that can ONLY use the functions printf and putchar, and can take very large large integers

Tags: arrays, c, math, printf

`Usage: ./calculator.c <operand one> <operator> <operand two>`

Operand one and two must be positive integers greater than or equal to zero. They can each have a maximum of 999 digits, and their sum can thus have a maximum of 1000 digits. We can assume that no operands will start with 0, for example stuff like 0009738 will not be passed. We only want to deal with addition for this calculator. **No other functions other than printf and putchar can be used for this.**

I have dealt with most of this but I am having trouble with the last part. Checking to see if the operator was '+' was straight forward. I checked the initial argument to see if they are positive integers by running while loops on each of the operands like this:

```
while (argv[1][i] != '\0'){
    if(argv[1][i]>57 || argv[1][i]<48){
.....Printing appropriate error messaage 
return;
   }
}
```

I ran the above code on each of the operands and also included a counter for each of them that would tell me how many digits each one is. At this point I have int max, which I have gotten from comparing the counters. I have an idea of the algorithm to add the numbers (using mod 10 to get the digit that will be placed, and divide by 10 to get the carry). I initialized three arrays as follows:

```
char first [max +1];
char second [max + 1];
char sum [max + 1];
```

I just don't know how to implement this/move forward from here. Could someone help me out? Again I must remind you that the **only** functions that can be used are printf and putchar, which makes this different than the over questions I went through here on SO.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. What the hex is 48? The character "digit 0" is spelled `'0'`, not `48`.

Comment: Can you describe how you would do this with pencil and paper?

Comment: Start from  something less complicated. For example function that adds large numbers.

Comment: do not use `mod` the stuff you are working with will not fit into standard int... you have to do this on strings (`char*`) ... addition will be just single for cycle looping from lowest digits to highest ones ...

Comment: the ASCII characters between 48 and 57 correspond to the digits between 0 and 9, both inclusive. The way I would do it on paper is exactly as I described above. So for example if I had two numbers A=a1a2a3a4a5  and B=b1b2b3b, where ai and bi represent the digits, I would do temp= a5 + b3. I would right down temp%10 on the line, and carry forward the floor of temp/10. Then add floor of temp/10 + a4 + b2, do the same procedure and so on

Comment: @user140161 why to use floats to just add 2 chars together ... try this in a loop (iterating through all digits from lowest): `cy=0; for (i=???;i;i--){ c[i] = a[i]+b[i]-'0'+cy; if (c[i]>'9'){ c[i]-=10; cy=1; }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have calculated already the number of digits for the two operands, you can loop from the end of the two arrays of characters for op1 and op2, convert each char ascii to int do the addition digit by digit then convert back to ascii and store in the output array while keeping the remainder. I would handle the case if the output size equals to the maximum possible size in a separate if condition as shown below:

```
//f_d num of digits of 1st operand
//s_d num of digits of 2nd operand
int sum=0,ind=0,max=0;
max=(f_d>s_d)?f_d:s_d;
while(ind<max){
    sum=sum/10; //Remainder
    if(f_d!=0) {sum+=argv[1][(f_d--)-1]-48};
    if(s_d!=0) {sum+=argv[3][(s_d--)-1]-48};
    output[max-1-ind++]=(sum%10)+48;
}
output[max]='\0';
if (sum/10!=0){
    int ind=max+1;
    while(ind!=0){
        output[ind--]=output[ind-1];
    }
    output[0]=sum/10+48;
}
```

Comment: f_scan=&argv what does the '&' do here?  And can you explain how this bit works max=(f_d>s_d)?f_d:s_d; ? What is f_d and s_d? and what does '?' do? What is happening here in general? Sorry I am very new to c and still very unfamiliar with syntax

Comment: The & is to get the address of the first char in the arg. Same as if we remove it and remove the '[0]' I will edit this part to be cleaner.  The ? refers to the ternary operator, you can find an explanation here https://www.javatpoint.com/conditional-operator-in-c. f_d and s_d are the number of digits of the first and second operands which you said you  can calculate (if op1=1234, op2=123 -> f_d=4, s_d=3)

Comment: why cant we simply do char f_scan []= argv[3]? why are we using char*?

Comment: No. char f_scan [] is equivalent to constant pointer to char so you cannot change the value of f_scan itself later. But we use f_scan and s_scan to loop on the elements of the arrays. You can avoid pointers at all and use integer indices as well.

Comment: So I tried this out and the shell hangs if the number of digits in the first number are more than the number of digits in the second one. However it works correctly if the second number has more digits than the first. So 250 + 50 hangs the shell, but 50 + 250 displays the correct output

Comment: I tried it and it works for me. Are you sure that you get f_d and s_d correctly? The only missing thing here is the end char which I can add but it is not the thing that make it hang.

Comment: For the first while loop, can you please add {} bracks around the code for the if statements, just so that I can see more clearly what exactly is happening if the if statements evaulate to true?

Comment: It will just execute the first line after the if if the condition is true

Comment: Got it to work correctly. The only problem is that when adding very large numbers, it fails to output the very last digit of the sum. So if the the true sum is 666666666678, it outputs 66666666667. I was initially using putchar but I also tried printf but that gives me an entirely different answer. What would be the best thing to do here?

Comment: I am not sure how do you use printf but this should give you correct result "printf("%s\n",output);" . If you want to use putchar then you have give the function char by char.

Comment: It outputs the correct result followed be ```'$!```. This is how I initialized the output array before running the code that you posted:  ```char output[max]; ```

Comment: It should be char output[max+1]. It suppose to work fine, you can use printf to print the intermediate calculations. Make sure that you have calculated the number of digits correctly and that you put the end char '\0' at the end as shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224267/discussion-between-user140161-and-maxis).